# How to Find the word that comes after a specified word in java String

Tags: java, string

My program has a String inputted Eg. hello i am john who are you oh so i see you are also john i am happy

my program then has a keyword inputted Eg. i (the program doesn't like capitals or punctuation yet)

then it reads the initial String and finds all the times it mentions the keyword + the word after the keyword, Eg. i am, i see, i am.

with this is finds the most common occurrence and outputs that second word as the new keyword and repeats. this will produce
i am john/happy (when it comes to an equal occurrence of a second word it stops (it is meant to))

What i want to know is how i find the word after the keyword.

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeepWriterMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        String next;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("text:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("starting word:");
        String start = scanner.nextLine();
        input.toLowerCase();
        start.toLowerCase();
        if (input.contains(start)) {
             System.out.println("Loading... (this is where i find the most used word after the 'start' variable)");
             next = input.substring(5, 8);
             System.out.println(next);
         }else {
             System.out.println("System has run into a problem");
         
         }
    }
```

---

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `split` to split all your words into an array, you can iterate through the array looking for the keyword, and if it is not the last in the array, you can print the next word

```
String arr [] = line.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
    if (arr[i].equalsIgnoreCase(keyword)) {
       sop(arr[i] + " " arr[i + 1]);
    
}
```

- if it is not the last in the array, iterate only to length - 1

Comment: what is sop? is it a string output or ?

Comment: sop = `System.out.println`

Answer (score 0):

The String class includes a method called `public int indexOf(String str)`. You could use this as follows:

```
int nIndex = input.indexOf(start) + start.length()
```

You then only need to check if `nIndex == -1` in the case that `start` is not in the input string. Otherwise, it gets you the position of the first character of the word that follows. Using the same `indexOf` method to find the next space provides the end index.

This would allow you to avoid a linear search through the input, although the indexOf method probably does one anyway.

Comment: I read this and didn't understand but kept working on it without looking at StackOverflow     and got pretty much the same result